# Python json config file

Tags: python, json

I wrote json configuration file:

```
{
"file": {"file_name": "file.xls"}, 
"names1": 
    {"Joe Allen": "JOE", 
     "Leo Messi": "MESSI"}
}
```

It is formatted and readable. I use function to change file_name:

```
def plik(self, evt):
    wildcard = "MS excell (*.xls)|*.xls"
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "",     wildcard, wx.OPEN)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        config['file'] = {'file_name': dialog.GetFilename()}
        with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(config, f)
        self.Destroy()
        frame = Program()
        frame.Show()
```

After change text in json file looks like:

```
{"file": {"file_name": "file.xls"},"names1":{"Joe Allen": "JOE","Leo Messi": "MESSI"}}
```

What should I do to keep formating.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by  `json.dump(config, f, sort_keys=True, indent=2)`. Indent was a key here. Simple solution.